# How can i run system->import/export->export by Command ssh

Tags: magento-1.9, export, command-line, ssh

I get no valid data send error during product export via system->import/export->export. Actually this because of time out error. How can run this export by command ssh.

Comment: There is no short-cut to run that utility from command-line, unless you are willing to write a whole extension to modify the default functionality. Did you try cutting down the size of import file in smaller chunks ?

Comment: @Prateek : how can i export my all products

Comment: @Prateek : my sites consist 50k products

Comment: In that case, try Dataflow models instead. Yes, they will take time, but you'll be able to complete the task. Other option will be to go with some 3rd party extension.

Comment: @Prateek :  Dataflow models also same time out error, because of 50k products. is any possible using custom script to get download all products.

Comment: A single file, that instantiate Mage environment, loads chunk of products, say 1000 in each iteration, and writes that information to a file on disk should do the job. You'll be able to run that file via SSH as well. You'll need to decide which information you need from your catalog in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use below script to export all the products. Put this script in root folder. And check your **profile id**. You can check your **profile id** from

> System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles.

Use **profile id** according to your need.

```
<?php


set_time_limit(0);
//THIS SCRIPT JUST INITIALS THE PROFILE TO BE RUN VIA MAGENTO ADMIN "RUN PROFILE IN POPUP". Its the same thing as click just via this file that you can run via cron
$profileId = 1; // SYSTEM - IMPORT/EXPORT - DATAFLOW PROFILES PROFILES <-- you need to go into your magento admin and grab the exact profile ID

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
$profile->load($profileId);
if (!$profile->getId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('ERROR: Incorrect profile id');
}

Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$recordCount = 0;
$batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
echo "EXPORT COMPLETE. BATCHID: " . $batchModel->getId();
?>
```

You will get your csv file in `var/export` folder.

Comment: command complete,but products export not working https://snag.gy/N6cU4t.jpg

Comment: my $profileId  is right.

Comment: Please double check your code. It's working for me. Check your var/export folder to see your exported file.

Comment: @  Dinesh Yadav : i get error https://snag.gy/QfNivr.jpg how can i solve this

Comment: @ Dinesh Yadav : Countryofmanufacture error page https://snag.gy/kq2Bwo.jpg

Comment: if you are facing the memory size issue then run this command     "php -dmemory_limit=50G import_export.php"

Comment: export working good, is it possible export products via System->import/export->export,

Comment: How can i run system->import/export->export by Command ssh not dataflow profiles

Comment: @ Dinesh : How can i export category name instead of category id